How do you create a link that calls your Chrome custom engine keyword and specific search term?
I have custom search engines with shortcuts in Google Chrome. I frequently use and reuse the same shortcut and search term, such as "xx term", where "xx" is the shortcut that calls a search engine and "term" is the word I'm using for search.
How can I create a link in a document that will open my default browser and call "xx term?" I want to be able to click the link, my default browser opens, and "xx term" is put into the omnibox and executed.
I've attempted using the standard way of making links as below and it hasn't worked.
<a href="xx term">xx term</a>

Thank you.

You need to invoke chrome with a URL parameter. However, it's practically impossible to encode xx term, since the space character will become %20.

Just use the complete search engine URL. For example:
# superuser
<a href="https://superuser.com/search?q=some+term">some term</a>
# google
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=some+term">some term</a>

The only thing chromium-based "custom search engine" entries do is shorten the URL by pre-entering some of it, and filling in %s with your text:
https://superuser.com/search?q=%s


By default, you cannot search a built-in entry like @history (chrome://history/?q=%s in the background) using a document hyperlink. You would need to create a custom URL handler at the operating system level to handle chrome://-style URLs
